# C# String Length

Tags: c#

Why are those two string returning different values for length. "CertificateKey" is a property. It returns 41 for length. However, the equivalent constant string returns 40. If I copy the value of certificate as a constant, the length returns 41. Why?!?

```
// This is the property. Length 41
CertificateKey.Length
```

41

```
// This is a constant of the same string. Length 40
"9FE90CA8A4138F65E9E2C67D1F37B9D5B9919384".Length
```

40

```
// This is a copy of the value of the property above. Length 41
"‎9FE90CA8A4138F65E9E2C67D1F37B9D5B9919384".Length
```

41

Comment: Split the string in chars using [ToCharArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) and see what happens?

Comment: Possibly `CertificateKey` property contains hidden null character (`\u0000`), which explains why it returns 41 even the string has 40 visible characters. See also [string.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I copied and pasted your two string literals into [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) and found that I could reproduce your result, so then I printed each character like so:

```
var a = "9FE90CA8A4138F65E9E2C67D1F37B9D5B9919384";
var b = "‎9FE90CA8A4138F65E9E2C67D1F37B9D5B9919384";
foreach (char c in a) Console.WriteLine($"{(int)c:X}");
Console.WriteLine("---");
foreach (char c in b) Console.WriteLine($"{(int)c:X}");
```

And got the following result:

```
39
46
[...]
34
---
200E
39
46
[...]
34
```

`200E` is the [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

Comment: Joe yes I just discovered the 200E. It's the first char in CertificateKey. The question is now how is it getting there. That value comes from the Web.Config.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to discern how it got there. My best guess is that it got into the web.config the same way it got into my LINQPad program: someone copied and pasted it from a source where it was already present. But how it got into whatever the source data was, I couldn't say.

Comment: I deleted the Web.config entry, recreated it in NP++ and added it back to the Web.config. That worked. I'll have to attribute that one to bad data. Thanks all.

Comment: In my case, I have exactly same issue when I copy-paste text from "certificate info" window (dont remember exact name, common windows dialog for viewing certificates information).